# Using Springer lncs and biblatex - wrong heading is shown for last page

Tags: biblatex, header-footer, capitalization, lncs

I have a little problem with the Springer `llncs` class and `biblatex`. I use the parameter runninghead with the `llncs` class to show title and page number in the document head. At the last page where the bibliography is printed the header is set by `biblatex`. Means there is an other header as on the other pages. I couldn´t find a solution to solve this problem. When I´m using BibTeX instead of `biblatex` there is no problem.

Someone has an idea?

```
\documentclass[runningheads,a4paper]{llncs}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}                    
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}                
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}                        
\usepackage{microtype}    
\usepackage[
    style=numeric, 
    maxnames=1,
    bibencoding=latin1,
    backend=bibtex8,
    defernumbers=true,
    hyperref=true,
    alldates=long
]{biblatex}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{url}
\urldef{\mailsa}\path|martin@jena.de|    
\newcommand{\keywords}[1]{\par\addvspace\baselineskip
\noindent\keywordname\enspace\ignorespaces#1}

\begin{filecontents}{bachelorarbeit_lit.bib}
@ONLINE{java96,
    author = {{Sun Microsystems}},
    title = {JavaSoft ships Java 1.0},
    year = {1996},
    month = {1},
    url = {http://findarticles.com/p/articles/mi_m0EIN/is_1996_Jan_23/ai_17853565/?tag=content;col1},
    urldate = {2011-03-02},
    sortname = {Sun},
    keywords = {www}
}
\end{filecontents}

\bibliography{bachelorarbeit_lit}

\begin{document}

\mainmatter  % start of an individual contribution

% first the title is needed
\title{Social Media:\\
Schutzmaßnahmen für die eigenen Daten}

% a short form should be given in case it is too long for the running head
\titlerunning{Social Media: Schutzmaßnahmen für die eigenen Daten}

\author{Martin%
\thanks{Die vorliegende Arbeit wurde im Rahmen der Veranstaltung \enquote{Web-Security} verfasst.}%
}
%
\authorrunning{Social Media: Schutzmaßnahmen für die eigenen Daten}

\institute{Fakultät für Mathematik und Informatik\\
Friedrich-Schiller-Universität Jena\\
Carl-Zeiß-Straße 3, 07743 Jena, Deutschland\\
\mailsa\\
}

\toctitle{}
\tocauthor{}
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
The abstract should summarize the contents of the paper and should
contain at least 70 and at most 150 words. It should be written using the
\emph{abstract} environment.
\keywords{Social Media, Social Network, Schutzmaßnahmen für die eigenen Daten}
\end{abstract}

\section{Test}
Test TestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTest
TestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestT
estTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTest
Test TestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTest
TestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTest
TestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTest
Test TestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTest
TestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTest
TestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTest
Test TestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTest
TestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestT
estTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTest
Test TestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTest
TestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestT
estTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTest
Test TestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTest
TestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTest
TestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTest
Test TestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTest
TestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTest
TestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTest
Test TestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTest
TestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestT
estTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTest
\cite{java96}
Test TestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTest
TestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestT
estTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTest
Test TestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTest
TestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTest
TestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTest
Test TestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTest
TestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTest
TestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTest
Test TestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTest
TestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestT
estTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTest
\cite{java96}
Test TestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTest
TestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestT
estTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTest
Test TestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTest
TestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTest
TestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTest
Test TestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTest
TestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTest
TestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTest
Test TestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTest
TestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestT
estTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTest
Test TestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTest
TestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestT
estTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTest
Test TestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTest
TestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTest
TestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTest
Test TestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTest
TestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTest
TestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTest
Test TestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTest
TestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestT
estTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTest
Test TestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTest
TestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestT
estTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTest
Test TestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTest
TestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTest
TestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTest
Test TestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTest
TestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTest
TestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTest
Test TestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTest
TestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestT
estTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTest
Test TestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTest
TestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestT
estTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTest
Test TestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTest
TestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTest
TestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTest
Test TestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTest
TestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTest
TestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTest
Test TestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTest
TestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestT
estTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTest


\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could e.g. suppress the heading printed by biblatex:

```
\section*{\bibname}
\printbibliography[heading=none]
```

Comment: I think the question is about the header/footer, not the heading.

Comment: @lockstep: Yes I know. But the default heading also sets the header (as it contains a `\mark` command). That's why I added the heading manually with `\section*`.

Answer (score 3):

Contrary to the `article` class, the `llncs` class doesn't use `\MakeUppercase` to typeset headers. You may change the definition of `biblatex`'s `bibliography` bibheading to emulate `llncs`'  behaviour.

```
\documentclass[runningheads,a4paper]{llncs}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\makeatletter
\defbibheading{bibliography}[\refname]{%
    \section*{#1}%
%    \markboth{\MakeUppercase{#1}}{\MakeUppercase{#1}}}% DELETED
    \markboth{#1}{#1}}% NEW
\makeatother

\begin{filecontents}{bachelorarbeit_lit.bib}
@ONLINE{java96,
    author = {{Sun Microsystems}},
    title = {JavaSoft ships Java 1.0},
    year = {1996},
    month = {1},
    url = {http://findarticles.com/p/articles/mi_m0EIN/is_1996_Jan_23/ai_17853565/?tag=content;col1},
    urldate = {2011-03-02},
    sortname = {Sun},
    keywords = {www}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{bachelorarbeit_lit.bib}

\nocite{*}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\title{(Title)}
\author{(Author)}
\maketitle

\section{Test}

\lipsum[1-12]

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```